# Como responder programaticamente a um comando no terminal Linux?

Tags: python, linux

Tenho um script em Python que executa um determinado comando no sistema. Esse comando espera que uma senha seja digitada logo em seguida, a única forma de funcionamento é essa, não é possível passar a senha via argumento.

Queria saber se existe alguma forma de executar o comando e a senha sem precisar da interação do usuário.

Comment: Poderia detalhar mais, qual seria o comando?

Comment: To tentando fazer um dump em um banco de dados. As alternativas que achei são usando variável de ambiente, mas quero fugir disso. Depois de digitar o comando dump o terminal fica: "Passoword:" esperando que o usuário digite a senha.

Comment: Qual banco de dados? Por favor coloque a linha como você está  usando.

Adiantaria pedir a senha pelo Python e entrar com ela na linha de comando por parâmetros?

Comment: Caso o comando permita, é possível concatenar a string e jogar com um parâmetro `-p` ou `--pasword` no `os.system()`, por exemplo: `os.system("comando -p "+password)`, mas eu não sei se é isso que você quer.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes Postgres. Comando: pg_dump -U user_name -h host -C -f file_name.dump databasename. Quero que o script seja automatizado, sem que interação com o usuário.

Comment: @felipe.avelar, o comando não tem o parâmetro password.

Comment: Pelo que eu dei uma lida, só alterando a variável de sistema mesmo. Porque, na verdade, o comando não tá rodando "dentro" do Python, o Python faz uma requisição de processo ao SO e quem executa esse comando é o próprio SO e não o Python. Deu pra entender o que eu quis dizer ou ficou meio confuso?

Comment: @felipe.avelar, entendi sim. Já tinha visto isso mas queria evitar. Criando uma variável de sistema um simples echo exibiria a senha. Via script teria algumas alternativas de evitar esse problema.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você não precisa de tudo isso, tudo o que você tem que fazer é criar um arquivo .pgpass no diretório home do usuário que irá executar o comando. O arquivo deve ter permissão de leitura/escrita apenas para este usuário por questão de segurança.
A sintaxe do arquivo é a seguinte:

```
maquina:porta:bancodedados:usuario:senha
```

Desta forma as ferramentas padrões não irão solicitar a senha para as configurações definidas no arquivo.

Answer (score 6):

Estive lendo um [artigo](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_subprocess_module.php) sobre o Python Subprocess Module, especificamente sobre o `subprocess.Popen`, que explica como o Python permite fazer uma comunicação com o processo executado.

Fiz um pequeno exemplo para Windows (desculpe, não tenho um Linux para testar isso agora) que muda a data do sistema:

```py
import subprocess

processo = subprocess.Popen(args = ['date'], 
                            stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stderr = subprocess.PIPE, 
                            shell = True)
processo.communicate(b'01-01-01')
```

O código acima foi testado na implementação padrão do Python (CPython) versão 3.3. Note que a linha `processo.communicate(b'01-01-01')` envia o valor `01-01-01` para o comando `date`.

A saída do console é:

```
The current date is: Tue 01/28/2014 
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy) 01-01-01
```

Acredito que você possa adaptar o comando `Popen` para executar o *dump* e em seguida enviar  a senha através do método `communicate`.

Comment: ótimo! Vai me servir para outras tarefas com certeza.

Answer (score 2):

Em sistemas *nix você pode enviar dados como input a outro comando usando *pipes* `|`. A ideia é que quando você escrever `cmd1 | cmd2` a saída do comando 1 será a entrada do comando 2, ou seja, eles ficam conectados. No final tudo que você verá será a entrada do comando 1 e a saída do comando 2. Você pode executar o seguinte:

```
echo "minhasenha" | seu_comando
```

A melhor alternativa, no entanto, é usar o [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) do Python para ter acesso às streams de entrada e saída do processo criado, te dando mais controle sobre o que acontece. Veja a [resposta do utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2518/como-responder-programaticamente-a-um-comando-no-terminal-linux#2521) para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Use o [pExpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Examples), que fornece dentre outras funcionalidades, algo que se parece com o **expect** do linux.

Veja um exemplo de como interagir com uma sessão `TELNET`

```
import pexpect
import sys,time
ipaddr = "192.168.0.81"
username = "usuario"
password = "minhasenha"
telconn = pexpect.spawn("telnet " + ipaddr)
telconn.expect(":")
telconn.logfile=sys.stdout
time.sleep(15)
telconn.sendline(username + "\r")
telconn.expect(":")
telconn.sendline(password + "\r")
time.sleep(30)
telconn.expect(">")
print "Logado com Sucesso"
```

No Exemplo acima, a variavel é enviada apenas quando a intrução "esperada" é atingida, no caso telnet, foi esperado por `:` algumas vezes, e impresso `Logado com Sucesso` após esperar por `>`